# VBA Excel table range and hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

The execution crash on this line at the end of my sub after I added some hyperlinks in an other column (`Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed`).

```
Range("TABLE_XXX[[#All],[COLUMN1]]")
```

When I go in debug and press F8 it works.
If I delete the code that puts hyperlinks it works like a charm.

Here is the code to add the hyperlinks

```
With mySheet
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(depRow, urlCol), _
    Address:="https://www.google.com/", _
    ScreenTip:="Google", _
    TextToDisplay:="https://www.google.com/"
End With
```

Any idea of what happens ?

EDIT : I just wrote a sample that reproduce perfectly the bug.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim objTable As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:B2"), , xlYes)
    objTable.Name = "TABLE_XXX"
    objTable.ListColumns(1).Name = "col1"
    objTable.ListColumns(2).Name = "col2"

    Set rng = Range("TABLE_XXX[[#All],[col1]]")

    With ActiveSheet
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(2, 2), _
        Address:="https://www.google.com/", _
        ScreenTip:="Google", _
        TextToDisplay:="https://www.google.com/"
    End With

    Set rng = Range("TABLE_XXX[[#All],[col2]]")
End Sub
```

The first `Set rng` works but the second one don't (except in debug).

Comment: Your `Range` has no worksheet specified: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range("TABLE_XXX[[#All],[COLUMN1]]"`. Finally I recommend to use the syntax as shown in [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) to access tables insead of using `TABLE_XXX[[#All],[COLUMN1]]`.

Comment: Doesn't work too with specifying the sheet. I tried it on the sample that i added to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
Set rng = Range("TABLE_XXX[[#All],[col2]]")
```

with

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TABLE_XXX").ListColumns("col2").Range
```

Comment: Ok I just replaced it by `Range("TABLE_XXX[col2]")` and it works. I'll probably never know why the first one doesn't works with the hyperlinks but it's ok. I just need to get the col2 to apply my sort and not all the range to be sorted. Of course your syntax works too.